# Show that the locus of the centroids of equilateral triangles inscribed in the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is the parabola $9y^2-4ax+32a^2=0.$

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that the locus of the centroids of equilateral triangles inscribed in the parabola $y^2=4ax$ is the parabola $9y^2-4ax+32a^2=0.$

I tried to solve it.I took three coordinates of the equilateral triangle as $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$

let the coordinates of the centroid be $(h,k)$.

$h=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3},k=\frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}$

$h=\frac{y^2_1+y^2_2+y^2_3}{12a}$

But eliminating $y_1,y_2,y_3$ is difficult.Is my method correct or is there any other better method.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to try yourself, translate into algebra the fact the triangle of vertices $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ is equilateral. Two equations are enough since congruence is transitive: don't use distance but orthogonality.
Then you need some algebraic manipulations to get the result.

Otherwise the complete solution is in Gelca,Andreescu [*Putnam and Beyond*](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lototsky/PiMuEp/PutnamAndBeyond-Andreescu.pdf) (2007), pp. 213-214.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the solution from Gelca,Andreescu *Putnam and Beyond* (2007), pp. 213-214 as Tony suggested:

---

> Let us determine first some algebraic conditions that the coordinates $(x_i, y_i)$,
> $i = 1, 2, 3$, of the vertices of a triangle should satisfy in order for the triangle to be equilateral. The equation of the median from $(x_3, y_3)$ is $$\dfrac{y-y_3}{x-x_3}=\dfrac{y_1+y_2-2y_3}{x_1+x_2-2x_3}$$
> or $$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2-2x_3)+(y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2-2y_3)=0$$
> So this relation along with the two obtained by circular permutations of the indices are necessary and sufficient conditions for the triangle to be equilateral. Of course, the third
> condition is redundant. In the case of three points on the parabola, namely $\left(\dfrac{y_i^2}{4a},y_i\right)$ , $i=1,2,3$, after dividing by $y_1-y_2$, respectively, by $y_2-y_3$ (which are both nonzero), we obtain $$(y_1+y_2)(y_1^2+y_2^2-2y_3^2)+16a^2(y_1+y_2-2y_3)=0 \\ (y_2+y_3)(y_2^2+y_3^2-2y_1^2)+16a^2(y_2+y_3-2y_1)=0$$
> Subtracting the two gives $$y_1^3-y_3^3+(y_1-y_3)(y_2^2-2y_1y_3)+48a^2(y_1-y_3)=0$$
> Divide this by $y_1-y_3 \ne 0$ to transform it into $$y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+3(y_1y_2+y_2y_3+y_3y_1)+48a^2=0$$
> This is the condition by the $y$ -coordinates of the vertices of the triangle. Keeping in mind that the coordinates of the centroid of the triangle are $$x=\dfrac{y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2}{12a}, y=\dfrac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3}$$ we rewrite the relations as $$-\dfrac{1}{2}(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2)+\dfrac{3}{2}(y_1+y_2+y_3)+48a^3=0$$ then substitute $12ax=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2$ and $3y=y_1+y_2+y_3$ to obtain the equation of the locus $$-6ax+\dfrac{27}{2}y^2+48a^2=0$$ or $$9y^2-4ax+32a^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the centroid be $G(h,k)$ and the vertices be $P(t_1), Q(t_2), R(t_3)$ in parametric form.

Since $G$ is also the circumcenter, we have that $P,Q,R$ lie on the circle of the form $x^2+y^2-2hx-2ky+c=0$

Setting $x=at^2, y=2at$ we get

$a^2t^4+(4a^2-2ah)t^2-4akt+c=0$

Noting that the sum of roots is zero, the roots of the above quartic are then $t_1,t_2,t_3, -(t_1+t_2+t_3)$

Considering roots taken two at a time,

$t_1t_2+t_2t_3+t_3t_1-(t_1+t_2+t_3)^2 = \dfrac{4a^2-2ah}{a^2}$

We have $3h =a(t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2)$ and $3k = 2a(t_1+t_2+t_3)$

The above relation can be written as $t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2+(t_1+t_2+t_3)^2 = \dfrac{2(2ah-4a^2)}{a^2}$ or

$\dfrac{3h}{a}+\left(\dfrac{3k}{2a}\right)^2 = \dfrac{2(2ah-4a^2)}{a^2}$

from which we get that $G$ lies on $9y^2-4ax+32a^2=0$